# Xmlrpc ServerProxy returns socket.gaierror

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to connect to a Magento API using Xmlrpc.

When the url is valid, i have no problem. But i'd like to catch errors if the url is not valid. If i try with an invalid url i have :

*socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known*

I'm trying to catch it but i can't find a way to do it ..
I'm using **Python 3.5** :

```
from xmlrpc.client import ServerProxy
from socket import gaierror

params = {
    "encoding: "utf-8",
    "verbose": False,
    "transport": SpecialTransport() # I use a SpecialTransport class
}

try:
    client = ServerProxy("https://ma.bad.url, **params)
except gaierror:
    print("Error")
```

The problem is, that i never go through the except ..

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering to myself.
I've finally been able to make it works like this :

```
    # Connect to the url
    client = ServerProxy('https://my.bad.url', **params)

    # Try to login to Magento to get a session
    try:
        session = client.login('username', 'password')
    except gaierror:
        # Error resolving / connecting to the url
        print('Connection error')
        sys.exit(2)
    except Fault:
        # Error with the login
        print('Login error')
        sys.exit(2)
    else:
        print('Success')
```